# Why is the passive לֹ֖א יֵֽאָכֵֽלוּ used in Devorim 14 (19) rather than the active form used elsewhere?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-reeh

[Devorim 14 (19)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9978/jewish/Chapter-14.htm) says

יט    וְכֹל֙ שֶׁ֣רֶץ הָע֔וֹף טָמֵ֥א ה֖וּא לָכֶ֑ם לֹ֖א יֵֽאָכֵֽלוּ:

19    And every flying insect is unclean for you; they may not be eaten.

The possuk uses the passive לֹ֖א יֵֽאָכֵֽלוּ instead of the active form used elsewhere in this chapter e.g.

v3 לֹ֥א תֹאכַ֖ל

vv 8, 10 לֹ֣א תֹאכֵ֔לוּ

v 21 לֹא־תֹֽאכְל֣וּ

Why is this?

Comment: Consider Pesachim 21b

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, no mainstream Mefarshim here make any comment whatsoever.

However, there is a parallel Passuk (which uses the same term) in Shemini ([Vayikra 11:13](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Vayikra/11.13#e0n7)), and Rashi there suggests that this means that one may not feed them to others.  See the Mefarshei Rashi at the above link for a full analysis of this.

---

Note that this doesn't make any difference to the practical ruling, as per Rambam Maachalos Asuros 8:14:

> כל מקום שנאמר בתורה לא תאכל, לא תאכלו, לא יאכלו, לא יאכל--אחד איסור אכילה, ואחד איסור הניה במשמע:  עד שיפרט לך הכתוב, כדרך שפירט בנבילה "לגר אשר בשעריך תיתננה ואכלה" (דברים יד,כא); ובחלב שנאמר בו "ייעשה לכל מלאכה" (ויקרא ז,כד).  או עד שיתפרש בתורה שבעל פה שהוא מותר בהניה, כגון שקצים, ורמשים, ודם, ואבר מן החי, וגיד הנשה--שכל אלו מותרין בהניה מפי הקבלה, אף על פי שהן אסורין באכילה.

Comment: My 300th answer!

Comment: 300 is *shin*. Congrats, and don't "eat" your words ;-)